# Windows update Microsoft.NET Framework 4.6.1 for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net-mvc

I have a Windows 2012 server where I am getting this update as an important update.
"Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 for Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3102467)".

I have a .NET MVC application on this server with Identity impersonation. When this update is installed, the identity impersonation simply stops working. The identity impersonation is connecting with the Database server which is by policy (I cannot use SQL Server authentication). I do not understand why it is causing the issue. Please help

Comment: That KB is know for some problem. see there for some example; http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2016/02/10/on-net-framework-4-6-1-and-exchange-compatibility.aspx

Comment: Any suggestion as to how I can fix the problems? Or should I simply ignore this update?

Comment: Yes you can ignore it if it pose problem

Comment: So this update isn't necessary? It comes under "Important" updates.

Comment: You fix the incompatibility of your apps or you dont install that update. Your choice?